# Querystring Array Parameters in Python using Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have been trying to figure out how to use `python-requests` to send a request that the url looks like:

```
http://example.com/api/add.json?name='hello'&data[]='hello'&data[]='world'
```

Normally I can build a dictionary and do:

```
data = {'name': 'hello', 'data': 'world'}
response = requests.get('http://example.com/api/add.json', params=data)
```

That works fine for most everything that I do. However, I have hit the url structure from above, and I am not sure how to do that in python without manually building strings. I can do that, but would rather not.

Is there something in the requests library I am missing or some python feature I am unaware of?

Also what do you even call that type of parameter so I can better google it?

Comment: I dont think there is any feature in `requests` to build a url like that. You need to build it manually through code.

Comment: Thought these type of urls are `url with query string`.
But they dont have `[]` kind of thing in between.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What u are doing is correct only. The resultant url is same what u are expecting.

```
>>> payload = {'name': 'hello', 'data': 'hello'}
>>> r = requests.get("http://example.com/api/params", params=payload)
```

u can see the resultant url:

```
>>> print(r.url)
http://example.com/api/params?name=hello&data=hello
```

According to [url format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding):

In particular, encoding the query string uses the following rules:

- Letters (A–Z and a–z), numbers (0–9) and the characters `.`,`-`,`~` and `_` are left as-is
- SPACE is encoded as `+` or `%20`
- All other characters are encoded as %HH hex representation with any non-ASCII characters first encoded as UTF-8 (or other specified encoding)

So  `array[]` will not be as expected and will be automatically replaced according to the rules:

If you build a url like :

```
`Build URL: http://example.com/api/add.json?name='hello'&data[]='hello'&data[]='world'`
```

OutPut will be:

```
>>> payload = {'name': 'hello', "data[]": 'hello','data[]':'world'}
>>> r = requests.get("http://example.com/api/params", params=payload)
>>> r.url
u'http://example.com/api/params?data%5B%5D=world&name=hello'
```

This is because Duplication will be replaced by the last value of the key in url and `data[]` will be replaced by `data%5B%5D`.

If `data%5B%5D` is not the problem(If server is able to parse it correctly),then u can go ahead with it.

[Source Link](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)

Comment: I agree with you everything you have said. Unfortunately, I have come across an API (http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Marketing_Emails_API/emails.html, look at 'Add multiple email recipients to a list') which is expecting multiple of the same keys. So need a way force duplicates or I need to build the parameter string manually.

Comment: yes as i said u can make it using string operations and use that url but `requests` library does not provoid that ,if u want to stick to `requests` .

Comment: Never hurts to hope. Going to mark this as the answer because it at least proves what I already thought.

Comment: This answer explains how requests are sent. However, if your API handles query parameter arrays correctly (as you can do with Django's `QueryDict.getlist()` method [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist]), then you can send query params like this and they will be fine. It's basically up to the API to handle the request if formed correctly.

Comment: that's not going to work  if u have more than  3  or more similar keys they will be overriden instead

Answer (score 118):

All you need to do is putting it on a list and making the key as **list like string**:

```
data = {'name': 'hello', 'data[]': ['hello', 'world']}
response = requests.get('http://example.com/api/add.json', params=data)
```

Comment: I hope the original user found this answer, because it exactly solves the problem with the SendGrid API. Thanks @Tomer.

Comment: Just doing `data = {'name': 'hello', 'data': ['hello', 'world']}` works fine too with requests (2.9).

Comment: @RémyGreinhofer That didn't work for me. I had to use Tomer's solution and I am using requests 2.10.

Comment: `data = {'name': 'hello', 'data': ['hello', 'world']}`
will be translated to:
`data=hello&data=world&name=hello`
and that's is not rfc compliant

`data = {'name': 'hello', 'data[]': ['hello', 'world']}`
will be translated to:
`data%5B%5D=hello&data%5B%5D=world&name=hello` (`data[]=hello&data[]=world&name=hello`)

Comment: @TomerZait can you refer and link the RFC that you mention?

Comment: Also works fine with `aiohttp`.

Comment: `'data[]': ['hello', 'world']` didn't work for me while simple `'data': ['hello', 'world']` worked! (I used FastAPI ).

Answer (score 9):

One solution if using the requests module is not compulsory, is using the `urllib`/`urllib2` combination:

```
payload = [('name', 'hello'), ('data[]', ('hello', 'world'))]
params = urllib.urlencode(payload, doseq=True)
sampleRequest = urllib2.Request('http://example.com/api/add.json?' + params)
response = urllib2.urlopen(sampleRequest)
```

Its a little more verbose and uses the doseq(uence) trick to encode the url parameters but I had used it when I did not know about the requests module.

For the requests module the answer provided by @Tomer should work.

Answer (score 1):

Some api-servers expect json-array as value in the url query string. The requests params doesn't create json array as value for parameters.

The way I fixed this on a similar problem was to use urllib.parse.urlencode to encode the query string, add it to the url and pass it to requests

e.g.

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
query_str = urlencode(params)
url = "?" + query_str
response = requests.get(url, params={}, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simply using the famous function: urlencode

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> params = {'q': 'Python URL encoding', 'as_sitesearch': 'www.urlencoder.io'}
>>> urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
'q=Python+URL+encoding&as_sitesearch=www.urlencoder.io'
```