# Python call URL with key=value pairs

Tags: python, url

Since I do my first steps in Python, I try to figure out, how can I do a simple URL call in Python with key=value pairs like:

```
http://somehost/somecontroller/action?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

I tried with some things like:

```
key1 = 'value'
key2 = 10
requests.get("http://somehost/somecontroller/action?key1=" + value + "&key2=" + str(10))
```

or

```
data={'key1': 'value', 'key2': str(10)}
requests.get("http://somehost/somecontroller/action", params=data)
```

(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974772/querystring-array-parameters-in-python-using-requests))

But this don't work. I also tried it by calling `curl` with `subprocess.Popen()` on different ways, but uhm...

I don't want to check the request, the URL call will be enough.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974772/querystring-array-parameters-in-python-using-requests#22975101

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I already tried this solution. It don't work for me.

Comment: I think you have typo `data = { 'key1': 'value', 'key2': str(10) }`. What error are you getting? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: Try `data={'key1': 'value', 'key2': '10'}; requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/", params=data)`, the url will be `http://127.0.0.1:5000/?key1=value&key2=10`.

Comment: There is no error, the url is simply not build for my needs. when I print the request.url it shows only "http://somehost/somecontroller/" in most of the cases. Missing the action and of course, the kay value part.

Comment: I know, its not working, cause the right url isn't called. There is a cakephp application, which is working fine, when i call the url over browser or curl from bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `requests` library you can use [`PreparedRequest.prepare_url`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.PreparedRequest.prepare_url) to encode the parameters to an url, like:

```
import requests
p = requests.models.PreparedRequest()

data={'key1': 'value', 'key2': str(10)}
p.prepare_url(url='http://somehost.com/somecontroller/action', params=data)

print p.url
```

In the last print, you should get:

```
http://somehost.com/somecontroller/action?key2=10&key1=value
```