# Multiple "where clauses" in endpoint query string parameters

Tags: python, eve

Can I include multiple "where" clauses (or an AND operator) in an endpoint query string? I'd like to do something like this:

```
http://localhost:5000/regions?where=name=="El Salvador"&where=lang=="es"
```

I've tried few different syntaxes, but I can't get it to work.

Is this possible? I know I can do it using MongoDB syntax, but I would like to use Python syntax.

Note: I'm not trying to concatenate an list of parameteres using python, I'm trying to use [Eve's filtering feature](http://python-eve.org/features.html#filtering) using native python syntax.

Comment: not sure what you are asking. Is this what you are looking for? `http://localhost:5000/regions?name="El Salvador"&lang="es"` This will allow you to filter on the endpoint using those 2 query string arguments.

Comment: @limbo I think it's not a duplicated question, I'm talking about Eve's syntax for filtering results through query string parameters.

Comment: @limbo have you used Eve ?

Comment: my bad, didn't use it, I should have looked into it a bit more. Guess I wasted a flag.

Comment: @limbo this I wha't I'm trying to do but with 2 "where  clauses" or an "AND" http://python-eve.org/features.html#filtering, look at "native python syntax"

Comment: I see now, what do you get with your current syntax, do you get the first filter working? Does it just ignore the part after the and?

Comment: can you try using                                                           `http://localhost:5000/regions?where=name=="El Salvador"&lang=="es"`

Comment: Thanks @limbo I tried that URL but the seconde parameter (and) is ignored, I get all results for name=="El Salvador" but with all the languages available (en, es, pt)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried `http://localhost:5000/regions?where=name=="El Salvador"%20and%20lang=="es"`?

You can replace `%20` for `space` in the `URL` if it doesn't work. In my postman environment works both ways.

Seems to work like the `AND` you want. The [documentation](http://python-eve.org/features.html#filtering) mentions it, but it misses an example I think. Mind the correct position for double quotes.

**EDIT:**

For boolean values, to filter `_deleted` is `False`, for example, the query format would be `http://localhost:5000/regions?where=name=="El Salvador" and not _deleted`

Comment: Yes, using MongoDB syntax works fine, I'm trying to do it using python syntax :)

Comment: @PachinSV I have updated the answer to use python syntax.

Comment: It worked using spaces http://localhost:5000/regions?where=name=="El Salvador" and lang=="en", you could update your answer to clarify that (you can use spaces or the html entity for a space %20)

Comment: Sure @PachinSV , just did that.

Answer (score 1):

[Querystring Array Parameters in Python using Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974772/querystring-array-parameters-in-python-using-requests) 

Looks like what you are after. The where clause is not necessary if you are using the '&' syntax so your clause should look something like this

```
http://localhost:5000/regions?name=='El Salvador'&lang=='es'
```

Comment: I test it, but it doesn't work.... in a matter of fact it does not apply any of the filters :(

Comment: are you using the python requests library like in the link I posted?