# how can i send images on my bot by using telegrams api?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Can anyone please show me how can I use the requests library in python to send photos from the internet?

I'm currently trying to send the photos as:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendPhoto-Fchat_id=<MY-ID>-Fphoto=https://random.dog/7e1527a4-9c07-48df-a877-4c6e4681adc1.jpg
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You pass the wrong url parameters.

Instead off `sendPhoto-Fchat_id` use the `?` and `&` sign. If you wish to add multiple parameters; take a look at [Querystring Array Parameters in Python using Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974772/querystring-array-parameters-in-python-using-requests/23347265)

`sendPhoto?chat_id=123&photo=somelink`

To answer the question, you can use the requests library like this:

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

url="https://api.telegram.org/bot<MY-TOKEN>/sendPhoto?chat_id=<MY-CHAT-ID>&photo=http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"

try:
    response = requests.get(url)

    # If the response was successful, no Exception will be raised
    response.raise_for_status()
except HTTPError as http_err:
    print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')  # Python 3.6
except Exception as err:
    print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')  # Python 3.6
else:
    print('Success!')
```